# Script to get projects urls using Gitlab API works in Jenkins Console but not in my scripted pipeline

Tags: groovy, gitlab, jenkins-pipeline, gitlab-api, flatmap

I'm Jenkins a beginner and I'm trying to write a jenkins scripted pipeline to dynamically fetch git urls of repos under a given Gitlab group.
I'm using gitlab4j-api which unfortunately does not provide a straightforward way to get all projects in a group and it's sub-groups.

So I'm writing a function to recursively flatmap sub-groups when found into projects, inspired by this link which does basically the same but for files and folders :
https://nurkiewicz.com/2014/07/turning-recursive-file-system-traversal.html

The issue is the script I wrote works fine when run in jenkins console, but when embedded in my pipeline it gives below error. Here's my code :

```
import java.util.stream.Stream
import org.gitlab4j.api.GitLabApi
import org.gitlab4j.api.models.Group
import org.gitlab4j.api.models.Project

url = "https://gitlab.domain.com"
token = "xxxxxxx"
groupPath = 'MY/GROUP'

gitLabApi = new GitLabApi(url,token)
println("Connected to Gitlab, version: "+ gitLabApi.getApiVersion())

getProjectsRecursive(groupPath).each { project -> 
  println project.getSshUrlToRepo()
}

def getProjectsRecursive(path) {
  //println 'getProjectsRecursive : ' + path
  return getDirectProjectsAndSubGroups(path).flatMap { projectOrSubgroup ->     
          projectOrSubgroup instanceof Group ? 
          getProjectsRecursive(((Group)projectOrSubgroup).getFullPath()) : 
          Stream.of((Project) projectOrSubgroup)
  }
}

def getDirectProjectsAndSubGroups(path2) {
    //println 'getDirectProjectsAndSubGroups : ' + path2
    def projectsAndGroups = []
    projectsAndGroups.addAll(gitLabApi.getGroupApi().getProjectsStream(path2).toList())
    projectsAndGroups.addAll(gitLabApi.getGroupApi().getSubGroupsStream(path2).toList())
    return projectsAndGroups.stream()
}
```

and here's the error :

```
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] echo
Connected to Gitlab, version: V4
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.flatMap() is applicable for argument types: (org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsClosure2) values: [org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsClosure2@2fd9965c]
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onMethodCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:158)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:178)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:182)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.methodCall(SandboxInvoker.java:17)
    at WorkflowScript.getProjectsRecursive(WorkflowScript:19)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:13)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationGroup.methodCall(ContinuationGroup.java:90)
```

**Edit** : As suggested by @MattSchuchard adding @NonCPS on both functions seems to be the right thing to do, but unfortunately this raises another error :

```
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] echo
Connected to Gitlab, version: V4
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.flatMap() is applicable for argument types: (WorkflowScript$_getProjectsRecursive_closure1) values: [WorkflowScript$_getProjectsRecursive_closure1@5795b4cf]
```

Comment: Is it possible to add a `@NonCPS` annotation to `getProjectsRecursive`, or would that break functionality for you?

Comment: @MattSchuchard Well that's exaclty what I did after some reading in Jenkins docs, and now I get another error, please see my edits on OP